# Switch column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables like this.

`MasterEntries` with columns:

```
  ParishName    AverageMark    
  Hanover         50.00
  Manchester      65.00
  Andrew          70.00
```

`MasterScoreSheet` with columns:

```
 Hanover      Manchester    [St.Andrew]
 50.00        65.00         70.00
```

I would like `AverageMark` column values from `MasterEntries` to become the values for the respective columns like this:

```
 Hanover      Manchester    Andrew
 50.00        65.00         70.00
```

How can I get this done?

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; please give a [mcve] of what you've tried and the specific problem with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to insert these values to the table `MasterScoreSheet`? 
You can do it like this:

```
insert into MasterScoreSheet (Hannover, Manchester, Andrew)
select
  (select AverageMark from MasterEntries where ParishName = 'Hannover'),
  (select AverageMark from MasterEntries where ParishName = 'Manchester'),
  (select AverageMark from MasterEntries where ParishName = 'Andrew');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e33180581244bb45d6a12a961f7b01f1).

Answer (score 1):

If the values are fixed to `"Hanover","Manchester","Andrew"` and you only have 3 rows then you can use `PIVOT()` method:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MasterEntries
     PIVOT(MAX(AverageMark) FOR ParishName IN ("Hanover","Manchester","Andrew")) AS AvgMark
```

- [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0ad09/9/0)

Answer (score 0):

I would write this query using conditional aggregation:

```
insert into MasterScoreSheet (Hannover, Manchester, Andrew)
    select max(case when ParishName = 'Hannover' then AverageMark from MasterEntries end),
           max(case when ParishName = 'Manchester' then AverageMark from MasterEntries end),
           max(case when ParishName = 'Andrew' then AverageMark from end)
    from MasterEntries;
```